# Too many keys in my inventory!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got thousands of keys in my inventory, which makes it really hard to find a certain one that I need. If I remove all the keys that I already used to unlock doors from my inventory will I still be able to open those doors?

Comment: Why do you want to find one?

Answer (score 6):

No, you won't. You need to be carrying them every time you want to open a door, because they get locked some time after you leave. It's just like when you pick a door once and when you return it becomes locked again. But don't worry. Keys have no weight and you don't have to choose a key to open a door. You just need to carry them. The game will choose the right key and unlock the door for you automatically when you go to open it.

Comment: I know that keys don't weight anything and the game choses the key for you. Thx for letting me know, I'll go back right now and grab them all from the chest in my house.

Answer (score 0):

It won't let you get rid of any that are quest-related if you haven't finished the quest. Why not buy a house and put them in a chest?

Comment: Yes thats what I've been thinking of but you didn't answer my question. Will I still be able to open the doors and chests I already unlocked with the key or will i need it every time to open them? Also, I have four houses so I'll have to pick a house! :P It's really nice having 300000+ gold in Skyrim! :D